# Business Rules Engine - Discrete Choice Modeling

Tags: frameworks, statistics, discrete-mathematics, architecture, business-rules

Greetings,

I am currently in search of a framework that could be used in the development of a system that will find the best option based on a series of responses provided by a user, in a closed survey format.

Our company offers several service plans, and the idea behind this system is that the user can respond to questions (text format), and these answers can be mapped to the service plan that best meets the customer's needs. Each service plan has several attributes, and these attributes change over time, so we are looking for a flexible solution.

Would a Business Rule Engine be an adequate framework for this type of problem?

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with a rules engine.

However, what you are actually building is a survey. There are lots of survey software that allows for the definition of conditionaly logic and branching within the survey.

It would probably be cheaper and faster for you to use survey software.